# Mechanical- Electrical circuit equivalence

Tags: circuit-analysis, mechanical

Is this the right electrical circuit equivalent to the mechanical?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk0Ex8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: where is your 1/B1 and 1/B3 ?

Comment: @placeholder I edit

Answer (score 1):

Your m2 in your circuit is connected to ground.  In the mechanical analog it is connected to M1.

Comment: Isn't it by low that mass suppose to be connected to ground? If not is my edit correct now?

Comment: looks proper now.

Comment: I think it isn't: 1/b2 suppose to be parallel to both m2 and m1 and in this case it isn't

Comment: 1/b2 is the resistance between M2 and M1 NOT M2 and ground.

Comment: but m1 suppose to feel the friction (b2) to.

Comment: Friction in electrical circuits is not as easy as you may think.  Resistance is a dispation ~velocity (current).  Friction is a loss ~distance (charge).

Answer (score 1):

Your capacitor M2 needs to have one end grounded, Otherwise your schematic looks OK.
[image: Corrected analogue]

The capacitors are always connected to ground when simulating a mass , this is because inertia is referenced to a stationary reference frame.  So for example if you push on a mass, you create a reaction force to ground with your feet, but the reaction force for the mass is swallowed up by the universe, so electrically you need to ground your capacitor so the reaction force can be returned as a "current", note that electrical "ground" (an infinite capacitor) is the same as "the universe" (an infinite mass) ,  ground voltage doesn't change no matter how much current you push into it, likewise the universe doesn't move no matter how much force you apply.
One of the tricky things with any modelling is setting the "boundary conditions" correctly.
Another common problem with analogues is not having a "DC path to ground" (your systems is OK), usually shows as a "floating node" error,  this can be solved by adding a 1gigohm resistor from any "floating nodes" to ground.